# AttributeError: 'Recognizer' object has no attribute 'recognize'

Tags: python, python-3.x

I  was trying the Speech Recognition module in Python (version 3.5) and have been getting the following error:

> 'AttributeError: 'Recognizer' object has no attribute 'recognize''

Here is the code I used:

```py
import pyaudio
import speech_recognition as sr

r = sr.Recognizer()
r.energy_threshold=4000

with sr.Microphone() as source:
    audio = r.listen(source)

try:
    print("Speech was:" + r.recognize(audio))
except LookupError:
    print('Speech not understood')
```

I found this code on Stack Overflow itself and also reading up the documentation from the Speech-Recognition module given [here](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/SpeechRecognition/), however it is not executing in my system for some reason.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

according to that [documentation](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/SpeechRecognition/) the `Recognizer` class don't have a method `recognize` and that is the meaning of the error you get, that come from

```
print("Speech was:" + r.recognize(audio))
```

here you are trying to call a method that don't exist, you have to use one of the several `recognize_*` method that the class offer instead, like `recognize_google`, `recognize_wit`, `recognize_ibm` or `recognize_att`

Answer (score 0):

The method has been changed from `recognize` to `recognize_google`. Your code should work with this change

```
import pyaudio
import speech_recognition as sr

r=sr.Recognizer()
r.energy_threshold=4000

with sr.Microphone() as source:
   audio=r.listen(source)

try:
   print("Speech was:" + r.recognize_google(audio))
except LookupError:
   print('Speech not understood')
```

Hope this helps you

Answer (score 0):

You must change `r.recognize(audio)` to `r.recognize_google(audio)` and run it by command line this way: `python3x path_your_file.py`.