# I was trying to convert speech to text and having bad error and don't know why,

Tags: python

My Code is having Bad error :
Code:

```
!pip install pipwin

!pipwin install pyaudio
# Audio to Text
!pip install pyttsx3
!pip install SpeechRecognition
import pyttsx3
import speech_recognition as sr
r = sr.Recognizer()
with sr.AudioFile('20211102_114210.wav') as source:
    audio = r.record(source)
    output = r.recognize(audio)
    print('OUTPUT: ' + output)
```

Error Statement :
ttributeError

```
 Traceback (most recent call last)

<ipython-input-24-3e877ae72a16> in <module>
     10 with sr.AudioFile('20211102_114210.wav') as source:
     11     audio = r.record(source)
---> 12     output = r.recognize(audio)
     13     print('OUTPUT: ' + output)
     14 

AttributeError: 'Recognizer' object has no attribute 'recognize'
```

I don't understand the error

Comment: Does this answer your question? [AttributeError: 'Recognizer' object has no attribute 'recognize'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34733871/attributeerror-recognizer-object-has-no-attribute-recognize)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Perhaps [this link] ([AttributeError: 'Recognizer' object has no attribute 'recognize'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34733871/attributeerror-recognizer-object-has-no-attribute-recognize/34734236)) will work for you. You can try

```
output = r.recognize_google(audio)
```

Answer (score 0):

When using speech recognition, I guess you need `listen` -

```
import pyttsx3
import speech_recognition as sr
r = sr.Recognizer()
with sr.AudioFile('20211102_114210.wav') as source:
    audio = r.record(source)
    output = r.listen(audio)
    print('OUTPUT: ' + output)
```

`recognize` is not a part of Speech Recognition Module. You need `listen`function